# Excel: Detecting an alphabet inside a column

Tags: excel, vlookup

I know how to use VLOOKUP, but can this be done in a single column?

For example:

```
      A          B          C
1    ABC         C      <formula>
2    DEF         G      <formula>
```

in C column, I want to make a formula to detect whether C & G are inside A column or not.
In this case, C1 should be TRUE & C2 should be FALSE.

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help. Here is the formula that you need.

```
=IF(ISERR(FIND(B1,A1))=FALSE,1,0)
```

That will see if the text in B2 is in A2 and will display true = 1, and false = 0 like binary.
This forum helped me find the answer for you: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=77416
I hope I can help.